# How do I change the host of the "Run Project" button in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am using Apache NetBeans IDE 15 with Java 17.

When clicking the "Run Project" (F6) button the browser successfully opens to :

https://localhost:8443/myProject

however I would like to have it go to :

https://localhost.xyz.edu:8443/myProject

How can this be done?

I was hoping this could have been changed via the Web Browsers Manager tool inside of Netbeans. However I am not sure what arguments are available besides URL.

screen shot of the Web Browsers Manager tool

[image: 1]

Comment: I haven't used NetBeans for a long while but, I seem to recall that the project URL one of the settings you have to enter when you create the PHP project: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html#phpProject

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for the tip however I just checked NB 15 and for Java Web projects providing a project URL no longer exists.